# HTML large background image

Tags: html

I've been ask to implement a site that is using a very large background image. Like 1600 X 900. It's 700K. I don't know how to make this smaller and still save it's quality. It's a black and white photo, I was saving it as a GIF. Any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use photoshop to save it as a jpeg at 60% quality. if you don't know how to save for web, when you want to save, hold ctl+alt+shift and the S button.

Comment: Yes. Generally a web background doesn't particularly need to be very hi-res as the general focus is on the main content and the bg should just be periferal eye candy.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop will show you a preview of the quality and the file size if you use 'save for web and other devices'

Unfortunately there are limits to how small a file can be before it starts to degrade. GIFs are usually more appropriate for smaller and fewer-color images like logos and buttons.

Because GIFs use indexed color, each pixel has a color byte associated with it which means that each pixel adds file size. In a JPG the file size is dependent on many factors, its usually the best option for non-geometirc images.

Answer (score 0):

Even if JPEG always has more colors than GIFs, you could convert it to Indexed colors and back to RGB, just to have a smaller number of colors in your JPEG. This will make it somewhat smaller.

Also of course raise the compression level.... 69% seems to work fine. Sometimes, you could go so low as 49% or so... try blurring the image - and you won't see the pixels as clearly.